# Can Azure Service Bus Sub/Topic implementation work for this approach?

Tags: azure, architecture, azureservicebus

I have potentially tens or even hudnreds of thousands of clients who need to communicate with a central server.

Communication is in the form of:

1. receive command from central servers (process it on the client)
2. respond with a status to central servers

I would like to avoid having the client machines talk to any intermediate web/API servers and instead, I want them to go directly to ASB

No client can see each other's messages. Whatsoever.  I understand I can use SAS tokens to provide temporary privilges to clients and renew them on a scheduled basis and that's great and works within my architecture.  However, I'm not sure if I can utilize the same ASB topic and have each client have their own topic inside?

Is ASB even the right technology for this?  Can I somehow maintain only two queues/service-bus subscriptions for this (request/reply) or must I create an individual queue for each indivdiual client?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

It’s difficult to tell without knowing more about the nature of the messages you are sending – e.g. how many are being sent. However, with this many clients you may be coming up against the quotas which are shown here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee732538.aspx

The salient limitations are:

- 100 concurrent connections per entity (i.e. topic, queue or subscription)
- 2,000 subscriptions per topic
- 10,000 queues or topics per service bus namespace
- 100,000 correlation filters per topic

It’s worth taking a look at the Azure scalability scenarios described in the second half of this document:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh528527.aspx

It may be possible to get the broadcast side of things going by getting clients to connect with correlation filters though I have not tried using them on this scale.

If you want to have lots of senders going to a single queue then you should consider using the Service Bus REST API for message sending.

Otherwise, I'm afraid you may want to consider a proxy...